# Как автоматически рассчитывать сумму в поле input

Tags: javascript

подскажите пожалуйста, как мне рассчитать сумму в поле input, с помощью js?
Я сделал по примеру в интернете расчет, но почему-то не работает. В скрипте даже alert не запускается, если его ставить после определения num1 и num2, если ставить до, то alert срабатывает.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function sumInputs() {

   var num1 = document.getElementById("col").value;
   var num2 = document.getElementById("cen").value;
   alert(num1);
   alert(num2);
   
   document.getElementById("sum").value = num1 + num2; 
}
</script>
```

```
<input type="text" name="Kol" required size="20pt" maxlength="30" placeholder="Количество" id="kol" oninput="sumInputs()"><br>
<input type="text" name="cena" required size="20pt" maxlength="30" placeholder="Цена" id="cen" oninput="sumInputs()"><br>
<input type="text" name="sum" required size="20pt" maxlength="30" placeholder="Сумма" id="sum" readonly><br>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: kol  вижу,  col - не вижу